# Is it possible to mark an anonymous function as "Live Code" so that Closure Compiler does not remove it?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, google-closure-compiler

How can I tell closure compiler that an anonymous function should not be removed as dead code?  I do not want to store the function to the window object.  I am looking for an alternative technique.

Say I have a javascript file that contains one giant anonymous function.

```
(function(){return "I am here!"})
```

For usage, I download this function via ajax and then capture the output of eval using something like

```
var f = eval('(function(){return "I am here!"})');
```

This assigns the anonymous function in the variable f.

```
d8> var f = eval('(function(){return "I am here!"})');
d8> f
function (){return "I am here!"}
d8> f()
I am here!
```

When I run the compiler over my js file that contains a single large anonymous function, the compiler "optimizes" my code by outputting nothing.  This is obviously not what I want.  Is there some sort of JSDoc I can put above my function to mark is as not being dead code?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Work around: (This isn't really what I wanted, but it seems to be the best result with the tools available)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I ended up using a combination of John and David's answers:

```
// code would be provided from an ajax request
var code = 'function F(){return "I am here!"};'

code = "("+code.replace(/\s*\;\s*$/, "")+");"

f = eval(code);
```

Giving the function a name makes the Closure Compiler happy.

Depending on the function, closure compiler will define variables outside of the function so I wrap the code in parenthesis to avoid defining global variables.

The replace method just moves the last semicolon used to separate the function definition so that it doesn't cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the function in the file without the wrapper, which would prevent the compiler from 'optimising' it, and then add the function wrapper when you eval it.

```
var code = 'return "I am here!";';
var f = eval('(function(){' + code + '})');
```

If your code really is 'invalid' without the function wrapper, you could leave it wrapped, but execute the wrapper, then continue as above. For example:

```
var code = '(function(){return "I am here!";}())';
var f = eval('(function(){return ' + code + '})');
```

Comment: The code inside the function block is not valid without the function wrapper so it will not compile. The compiler chokes with JSC_PARSE_ERROR

Comment: er, how is it not valid? can you post the code? Otherwise, try immediately executing the function wrapper and still wrap it again as I suggested

Comment: even the simple "I am here" code is invalid unless wrapped in a function because of the return statement: SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

Comment: Ah good point, in that case you can use the second example I posted, which should alleviate that.

Comment: I marked your code as the answer.  I tweaked it and placed it in the original question so I could format it.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler isn't built to work with code snippets. The only solution I see is to make the code valid.

```
var a = (function() {...})();
```

and post process the code to strip off the parts you don't want.  Even this may not be workable in ADVANCED mode as it may try to inline the function.

Comment: I have tried this too.  Simple mode works okay, but advanced mode doesn't like it.  It also moves a var e = null; outside the function so a simple strip doesn't work.

Comment: If you are trying to use advanced mode, you can use the compiler's "output wrapper" and externs to accomplish what you want. With this wrapper:

    (function(){ var result; %output%; return result })

You want to be sure "result" doesn't conflict with a name in your code, and declare it in your extern definitions.